# Getting Google Translate saved words

Tags: google-translate

I've been using google translate for some years, saving those words which I wasn't aware of.

Is there any way to get my stored words (the starred translation ones) from my account via any **API**? I'm already concerned about the possibility of exporting an excel file.

I couldn't find such method on the API's explorer:

> **language.detections.list**  Detect the language of text.
>
> **language.languages.list**   List the source/target languages supported by
> the API
>
> **language.translations.list**    Returns text translations from one
> language to another.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want an API that lets you query and get your "saved" translations, so your phrasebook?

If that's it, then the short answer is : no.

Although, I know for a fact that there is an opened feature request for just this feature [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/detail?id=7&colspec=ID%20Type%20Product%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Priority%20Owner%20Log). To give it more traction, I'd suggest starring it as well. That'll also let you be notified of new posts on that thread.

Answer (score 4):

You can export your vocabulary to Excel format.
https://youtu.be/qsnrhF0HL_M